# Getting trouble in connecting with Google BigQuery

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I've been making api with flask on Google App Engine and When I send request to this app from browser after deploy, I got 502 error. I'm sure this error is caused by credential of GCP by "gcloud app logs tail -s test" but The path of credential Json file and file name seems OK . I have googled and I tried every articles I have found there but could not solve.
I have already done export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/secret_key/bq.json"
Could anyone tell me the solution??
If there is lack of any info , please let me know . Thank you .

besides, my api function is getting luid parameter over http request and run SQL with that luid and if the row of the luid has data in cv_date column in BigQuery, it returns True to client.

```
【The result of "gcloud app logs tail -s test"】

File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 97, in load_credentials_from_file      "File {} was not found.".format(filename)  google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File /home/user/secret_key/bq.json was not found.
```

```
【/home/user/api_dev/main.py】

from flask import Flask,request
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os

credentials_json = '/home/user/secret_key/bq.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credentials_json
client = bigquery.Client()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_request():
    request_luid = request.args.get('luid') or ''
    query = """
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT cv_date FROM `test-266110.conversion_log.conversion_log_202008*` t WHERE request_luid = p.luid)
    """
    query_res = client.query(query)

    return query_res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
【Remove the codes for BigQuery except import library and variables】
*This code works well and returns luid you input on url parameter 

from flask import Flask, request
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os

credentials_json = '/home/user/secret_key/bq.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credentials_json


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_request():
    request_luid = request.args.get('luid') or ''
    
    return request_luid


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend reading through the auth docs.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production talks about service account interactions in a bit more detail.  You likely don't need to pass in your credentials in the live app.  You can simply set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS when you're running locally to use the credentials, but you don't need to set it in production.

The issue is that the path you've specified (`/home/user/secret_key/bq.json`) is only valid for your development environment, and either not included in your production deployment at all or the absolute path to the file in the deployed app is different.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I checked it out over and over again and I realized maybe I don't need the process to use credential file because I run the SQL without t credentials , I got return from BigQuery.